# How to let excel to not detect the date value I enter

Tags: excel

Every time I enter the date format in the excel, it will automatically change the value I enter to date format, but I just want to keep what I enter.

For example, if I enter `11/21` in the excel,  it will automatically convert to `21/Nov`. But I really just want to have `11/21`.

Comment: Enter it as text.

Answer (score 2):

Put a single quote (`'`) before your date.
For example, `'11/22`